# Prevent StandBy closing MacBook lid during no power connection but Display connected

Tags: macbook-pro, display, sleep-wake

I have currently no power connection to my MacBook Air, but I have a Display connected. **I want to close the lid and only work on my external display.**

**So I want to prevent my MacBook going to StandBy when I close the lid.** When I have the power cable connected, it will just switch to the bigger screen. But when the connector isn't attached, it will go to sleep.

> How to prevent going to StandBy if no power connector is attached? Any
>   app or terminal command?

*I am running OS X Yosemite on a MacBook Air mid-2011.*

Comment: maybe give http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/ a try

Answer (score 1):

[NoSleep](https://github.com/integralpro/nosleep/releases) prevents sleep when lid is closed.

Answer (score -1):

there's an app called insomniax which can disable lid sleep for you, i was looking for the same thing as you but this is all i found..